# Java Method Argument Type to be from any type that contains method name

Tags: java

Is there a way to implement in Java Generics method
that the type is any type that has specific function name (not in inheritance ) ?

Comment: `The type has specific function name` -> Did they got it from interface or parent class? If you want to use generic to return type with specific method, you have to declare it somewhere (interface/superclass) first

Comment: Function *name*? Please explain why you need this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately it's quite unclear what you are asking. Could you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Not directly, but you could use a filter within your method using `getClass()`and throw an exception for example if the object is not from a type with string in its name. But frankly, I don't see where this could be needed. I smell some fishy architecture choices

Comment: Thanks you all , I just want to make sure if there is no way to do it without implement interface,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you are trying to use generics to only allow for types that implement a method with a certain name. They're called *methods*, not *functions*, in Java.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible directly. The best thing you can do is create an interface that contains the required method, have your classes containing the method implement it, and then use a generic type constraint for that specific interface type:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    int doSomething(int x, int y);
}
```

Do note that this requires that the entire signature be the same (not only the same name, but also the same parameters and a compatible return type). Your code would then look like this:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends SomeInterface> {
```

Also note that this will only work perfectly if all the classes you're using were made by you. If you're also using classes by someone else that have the same method signature, it should be possible to make your own class that extends the library class and is declared as implementing the interface, and use that class instead of the library class.

If you *really* need to check for methods that have the same name but not the same signature, there may be another way to do it using *reflection*. If you need that, please let me know in a comment.

Comment: Thanks , I just want to make sure if there is no way to do it without implement interface,so I understand that no.